# Columns order mixed up by style

Tags: attribute-table, fields-attributes, qgis-3

I have a point layer for wich I've set the order of columns while using field calculator and Refactor fields instruments. But the order of colums is different when I'm choosing point by Identify features or looking at the Attribute table. This happens only after I apply saved style for this layer. Without style applying everything goes right.

[image]
[image]

I need to make attribute table showing correct order of columns (as it is shown in Attributes Form). Where and what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

To organize columns in attribute table in proper order: Open attribute table, right click on any header of column and choose *Organize Columns..*. And in the next window drag and drop fields in the list in proper order.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, @PPZ, that helps for organizing columns. But my aim was to apply the style of the layer with a proper order of columns to another layer which has the same set of columns. 
1. After organizing columns the way you proposed I'm saving the style of this layer.
2. After applying that style to the next layer I'm still getting mixed order of columns. 
The only way wich works in my case - not to add Attribute Table into the list of style categories while saving it. Such style does not mix the order within the next layer...